# Converting string date to nanoseconds timestamp

Tags: python

I have a different time format than what I've found in different topics and I'm trying to convert it to timestamp.

```
timestamp_data= "2021-11-04 13:17:12.780000+00:00"
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp_data, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S.%f+%z")
```

but it doesn't work.

Looked through the strptime documentation but didn't find proper arguments to use to match my date format.

Comment: Remove the `+` in your format string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, remove the `+` in the format string.

```
timestamp_data= "2021-11-04 13:17:12.780000+00:00"
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp_data, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

will parse your string correctly.